# domain service - server side update

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, domainservices

I have a silverlight 4 RIA Domain Service. In one particular method I need to change one value in the database (among other things of course). To do this I get the entity, change the one value, then I need to save that change back to the DB.

I've tried calling the entity's generated update function, which just calls this.ObjectContext.myEntity.AttachAsModified(myENtity); but the change never gets back to the database.

How do I save values from the sever side (ie. the client never had this data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, attaching the object before or after the change makes no difference. 
The missing peice was :

this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

You should know that the UpdateXXX method doesn't actually submit the changes to the database - that only happens a bit later. knowing this, we can change the default implementation of the UpdateXXX method: (I'm assuming XXX == Product here)

```
    public void UpdateProduct(Product currentProduct)
    {
        this.ObjectContext.Products.AttachAsModified(currentProduct, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentProduct));
    }
```

to

```
    public void UpdateProduct(Product currentProduct)
    {
        // This line only reattach the entity back to EF context, it doesn't submit changes yet
        this.ObjectContext.Products.AttachAsModified(currentProduct, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentProduct));

        currentProduct.SomeProperty = "SomeChange"; // This change is going to be submitted later
    }
```

Comment: What I'm reading from your answer is that the Entity should be attached BEFORE the change is made. That makes sense, but the change is still not reaching the database. Is there anything else I need to call to make this actually sumbit later?

Comment: nope. There's a virtual method called Sumbit that is called after the UpdateXXX is called. - public override bool Submit(ChangeSet changeSet). It is called automatically by the DomainService class.